# Scaling a QTMovie before appending

Tags: macos, cocoa, scaling, quicktime, qtkit

Using the `QTKit` framework, I'm developing a little app.

In the app, I'm trying to append a movie after a other movie, which in essence is already working (most of the time), but I'm having a little trouble with the appended movie. The movie is which I'm appending to is quite big, like 1920x1080, and the appended movie is usually much smaller, but I never know what size it exactly is. The appended movie sort of stays its own size in the previous 1920x1080 frame, as seen here: [image]

Is there anyone familiar with this? Is there a way I can scale the movie which I need to append to, to the size of the appended movie? There is no reference of such a thing in the documentation.

This is are some relevant methods: 
`QTMovie *segmentTwo = [QTMovie movieWithURL:finishedMovie  error:nil];
            QTTimeRange range = { .time = QTZeroTime, .duration = [segmentTwo duration] };

```
        [segmentTwo setSelection:range];
        [leader appendSelectionFromMovie:segmentTwo];

        while([[leader attributeForKey:QTMovieLoadStateAttribute] longValue] != 100000L)
        {
            //wait until QTMovieLoadStateComplete
        }

        NSDictionary *exportAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieExport,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithLong:kQTFileTypeMovie], QTMovieExportType, nil];

        NSString *outputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov", onderwerp];
        NSString *filepath = [[@"~/Desktop" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", outputFile];
        BOOL succes = [leader writeToFile:filepath withAttributes:exportAttributes error:&theError];
```

Leader is initialized like this:

```
NSDictionary *movieAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:path, QTMovieFileNameAttribute, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieEditableAttribute,  nil];

leader = [QTMovie movieWithAttributes: movieAttributes  error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This contained all the information I need, although without using the QTKit framework. [QTKit - Merge two videos with different width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213088/qtkit-merge-two-videos-with-different-width-and-height)